# FOSUserBundle: trying to use a stylesheet for the login page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've installed FOSUSerBundle and overwrite the twig template. Now I want to use a custom .scss for the login template. So I have add this to the template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets filter="compass" "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/assets/css/prueba.scss" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

but it says:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("Unable to find file
>   "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/assets/css/prueba.scss".") in
>   "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig".

My file system is:

```
  ▾ app/
    ▾ Resources/
      ▾ FOSUserBundle/
        ▾ assets/
          ▾ css/
              prueba.scss
        ▾ views/
            layout.html.twig
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not in the FOSUserBundle, with this notation '@FOSUserBundle' assetic look only in the the FOSUserBundle folder (in vendor) not in your app folder.

Try with the full path ;)

Comment: what do you mean exactly with the full path? I have tried this: `{% stylesheets filter="compass" "bundles/canalonesbastimaruser/css/prueba.scss" %}` checking first the the file is there, but it is not loading it.., even if I write a wrong path, I dont get an error.. Im expecting the content of `prueba.scss` in the .css generated, is that right? I have another .scss and the content is taken to the generated .css without problems.